# Why does my C++ Asio TCP server disconnect previous clients when a new one tries to connect?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, connection, boost-asio

I tried setting up a simple client-server tcp program using Boost::Asio features wrapped up in my "physicalserver" and "physicalclient" classes. On connection, the server tries in a loop to send data to a client; the client waits in a loop for data from the server.
I tried creating simple and minimal examples showing the problem:

client.cpp:

```
#include "..\..\CppLibraries\Networks\client\physicalclient.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace dnw;

void connectionCallback(Client::Socket& socket, Client& client)
{
    std::cout << "Connected!\n";

    std::array<std::byte, 256> data;

    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(data));
        } catch(boost::system::system_error& e)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to receive! Server closed?\n";
            getch();
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    PhysicalClient client;

    client.setOnConnection(connectionCallback);

    try
    {
        client.connect("localhost", "10666");
    } catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Server didn't respond...\n";
        getch();
    }

    while(true);
}
```

server.cpp:

```
#include "..\..\CppLibraries\Networks\server\physicalserver.hpp"

using namespace dnw;

void connectionCallback(Server::Socket& socket, Server& server)
{
    std::cout << "Client connected!\n";

    std::array<std::byte, 256> data;

    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(data));
        } catch(boost::system::system_error& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to write! Client disconnected?\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    PhysicalServer server;

    server.setOnConnection(10666, connectionCallback);

    server.startListening(10666);

    while(true);
}
```

physicalclient.cpp:

```
#include "physicalclient.hpp"

#include <thread>

dnw::PhysicalClient::PhysicalClient()
:
    socket(context),
    resolver(context)
{

}

void dnw::PhysicalClient::connect(const std::string_view addr, const std::string_view port)
{
    if(socket.is_open())
    {
        return;
    }

    boost::asio::connect(socket, resolver.resolve(addr, port));

    std::thread thread {processor, std::ref(socket), std::ref(*this)};

    thread.detach();
}

void dnw::PhysicalClient::setOnConnection(const Processor& proc)
{
    processor = proc;
}

void dnw::PhysicalClient::disconnect()
{
    socket.close();
}

dnw::PhysicalClient::~PhysicalClient()
{
    disconnect();
}
```

physicalserver.cpp:

```
#include "physicalserver.hpp"

#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>

#include <iostream>

void dnw::PhysicalServer::startListening()
{
    for(auto& pair : ports)
    {
        startListening(pair.first);
    }
}

void dnw::PhysicalServer::stopListening()
{
    for(auto& pair : ports)
    {
        stopListening(pair.first);
    }
}

void dnw::PhysicalServer::startListening(const Port port)
{
    std::get<bool>(ports[port]) = true;

    std::thread thread {listen, this, port};

    thread.detach();
}

void dnw::PhysicalServer::stopListening(const Port port)
{
    std::get<bool>(ports[port]) = false;
}

void dnw::PhysicalServer::listen(const Port port)
{
    using namespace boost::asio::ip;

    static tcp::acceptor acceptor {
        context,
        {tcp::v4(), port}
    };

    while(std::get<bool>(ports[port]))
    {
        Socket socket {context};

        acceptor.accept(socket);

        auto& sockets {std::get<std::vector<Socket>>(ports[port])}; 

        sockets.push_back(std::move(socket));

        std::thread thread {std::get<Processor>(ports[port]), std::ref(sockets.back()), std::ref(*this)};
        
        thread.detach();
    }
}

void dnw::PhysicalServer::setOnConnection(const Port port, const Processor& proc)
{
    std::get<Processor>(ports[port]) = proc;
}

void dnw::PhysicalServer::closeConnection()
{
    for(auto& [key, tuple] : ports)
    {
        closeConnection(key);
    }
}

void dnw::PhysicalServer::closeConnection(Port port)
{
    auto& sockets {std::get<std::vector<Socket>>(ports[port])};

    for(auto& socket : sockets)
    {
        socket.close();
    }

    sockets.clear();
}

void dnw::PhysicalServer::closeConnection(Socket& socket)
{
    using std::get;

    auto& sockets {get<std::vector<Socket>>(ports[getSocketPort(socket)])};

    auto socket_iter {
        std::find_if(
            sockets.begin(),
            sockets.end(),
            [&](auto& s2)
            {
                return s2.local_endpoint() == socket.local_endpoint();
            } 
        )
    };

    if(socket_iter != sockets.end())
    {
        socket.close();
        sockets.erase(socket_iter);
    }
}

size_t dnw::PhysicalServer::getClientCount() const
{
    size_t total {};

    for(auto& pair : ports)
    {
        total += getClientCount(pair.first);
    }

    return total;
}

size_t dnw::PhysicalServer::getClientCount(const Port port) const
{
    return std::get<std::vector<Socket>>(ports.at(port)).size();
}

dnw::Server::Port dnw::PhysicalServer::getSocketPort(const Socket& socket)
{
    return socket.local_endpoint().port();
}

void dnw::PhysicalServer::applyOnClient(const std::function<void(Socket&)>& action)
{
    for(auto& [key, port] : ports)
    {
        applyOnClient(key, action);
    }
}

void dnw::PhysicalServer::applyOnClient(const Port port, const std::function<void(Socket&)>& action)
{
    std::for_each(
        std::get<std::vector<Socket>>(ports[port]).begin(),
        std::get<std::vector<Socket>>(ports[port]).end(),
        action
    );
}
```

I was expecting multiple client connections to be allowed; however, whenever I try to start a new client, the previous one gets disconnected (I get "Failed to write! Client disconnected?" from the server. I'm using different sockets for every client, so I don't know why the program is behaving this way.

Comment: I'm pretty confused. The code is nowhere minimal nor complete, and this question gets upvotes like no other Boost Asio post.

Answer (score 1):

Make that 1000x simpler. You will likely see your issue in a debugger.

E.g. start with

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4aa50e5460cf289)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <thread>
#include <tuple>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using Server = struct PhysicalServer;
using Client = struct PhysicalClient;
using Socket = tcp::socket;

struct PhysicalServer {
    using Port      = uint16_t;
    using Processor = std::function<void(Socket& s, Server&)>;
    using Conn      = std::tuple<bool, std::vector<Socket>, Processor>;

    std::map<Port, Conn>    ports;
    boost::asio::io_context context;

    void startListening() {
        for (auto& pair : ports) {
            startListening(pair.first);
        }
    }

    void stopListening() {
        for (auto& pair : ports) {
            stopListening(pair.first);
        }
    }

    void startListening(const Port port) {
        std::get<bool>(ports[port]) = true;
        std::thread{&PhysicalServer::listen, this, port}.detach();
    }

    void stopListening(const Port port) { std::get<bool>(ports[port]) = false; }

    void listen(const Port port) {
        using namespace boost::asio::ip;

        static tcp::acceptor acceptor{context, {tcp::v4(), port}};

        while (std::get<bool>(ports[port])) {
            Socket socket{context};

            acceptor.accept(socket);

            auto& sockets{std::get<std::vector<Socket>>(ports[port])};

            sockets.push_back(std::move(socket));

            std::thread{std::get<Processor>(ports[port]), std::ref(sockets.back()), std::ref(*this)}.detach();
        }
    }

    void setOnConnection(const Port port, Processor const& proc) { std::get<Processor>(ports[port]) = proc; }

    void closeConnection() {
        for (auto& [key, tuple] : ports) {
            closeConnection(key);
        }
    }

    void closeConnection(Port port) {
        auto& sockets{std::get<std::vector<Socket>>(ports[port])};

        for (auto& socket : sockets) {
            socket.close();
        }

        sockets.clear();
    }

    void closeConnection(Socket& socket) {
        using std::get;

        auto& sockets{get<std::vector<Socket>>(ports[getSocketPort(socket)])};

        auto socket_iter{std::find_if(sockets.begin(), sockets.end(), [&](auto& s2) {
            return s2.local_endpoint() == socket.local_endpoint();
        })};

        if (socket_iter != sockets.end()) {
            socket.close();
            sockets.erase(socket_iter);
        }
    }

    size_t getClientCount() const {
        size_t total{};

        for (auto& pair : ports) {
            total += getClientCount(pair.first);
        }

        return total;
    }

    size_t getClientCount(const Port port) const {
        return std::get<std::vector<Socket>>(ports.at(port)).size();
    }

    Server::Port getSocketPort(Socket const& socket) { return socket.local_endpoint().port(); }

    void applyOnClient(std::function<void(Socket&)> const& action) {
        for (auto& [key, port] : ports) {
            applyOnClient(key, action);
        }
    }

    void applyOnClient(const Port port, std::function<void(Socket&)> const& action) {
        std::for_each(std::get<std::vector<Socket>>(ports[port]).begin(),
                      std::get<std::vector<Socket>>(ports[port]).end(), action);
    }
};

using Client = struct PhysicalClient;
struct PhysicalClient {
    using Processor = std::function<void(Socket& s, Client&)>;
    boost::asio::io_context context;
    Socket                  socket{context};
    tcp::resolver           resolver{context};
    Processor               processor;

    PhysicalClient() : socket(context), resolver(context) {}

    void connect(const std::string_view addr, const std::string_view port) {
        if (socket.is_open()) {
            return;
        }

        boost::asio::connect(socket, resolver.resolve(addr, port));
        std::thread{processor, std::ref(socket), std::ref(*this)}.detach();
    }

    void setOnConnection(Processor const& proc) { processor = proc; }
    void disconnect() { socket.close(); }
    ~PhysicalClient() { disconnect(); }
};

#include <iostream>

void clientCallback(Socket& socket, Client& /*client*/) {
    std::cout << "Connected!\n";

    std::array<std::byte, 256> data;

    try {
        while (true) {
            auto n = boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(data));
            std::cout << "Received " << n << " bytes" << std::endl;
        }
    } catch (boost::system::system_error& e) {
        std::cout << "Failed to receive! " << e.what() << std::endl;
        // exit(1);
    }
}

void serverCallback(Socket& socket, Server& /*server*/) {
    std::cout << "Client connected!\n";

    std::array<std::byte, 256> data;

    try {
        while (auto n = boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(data))) {
            std::cout << "Sent " << n << " bytes" << std::endl;
        }
    } catch (boost::system::system_error& e) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to write! Client disconnected?\n";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char**) {
    if (argc > 1) { // server
        PhysicalServer server;

        server.setOnConnection(10666, serverCallback);
        server.startListening(/*10666*/);
        std::cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
    } else { // client
        PhysicalClient client;

        client.setOnConnection(clientCallback);

        try {
            client.connect("127.0.0.1", "10666");
        } catch (std::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << "Connection failure: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Some glaring errors are around the threads. The `detach()` is a strong sign that you are giving away control (there will not be a graceful shutdown).

Worse, you're liberally accessing `ports` across threads. That's a data race and the result is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Beyond, at least make the `bool` listening flag an `atomic_bool`.

The tuple abuse is really not doing you any favours either. Why not just have class instead?

```
//using Conn      = std::tuple<bool, std::vector<Socket>, Processor>;
struct Conn {
    bool                listening = false;
    std::vector<Socket> sockets;
    Processor           processor;
};

// ... 
ports[port].listening = true;
```

Or, even just use structured bindings on the tuple instead:

```
void listen(Port port) {
    static tcp::acceptor acceptor{context, {tcp::v4(), port}};

    auto& [listening, sockets, processor] = ports[port];

    while (ports[port].listening) {
        sockets.push_back(acceptor.accept());
        std::thread{processor, std::ref(sockets.back()), std::ref(*this)}.detach();
    }
}
```

Orders of magnitude better already. Next up, don't forget `local_endpoint` may throw (e.g. when the socket isn't valid anymore).

### Your Question

Likely, the most central issue is this:

```
static tcp::acceptor acceptor{context, {tcp::v4(), port}};
```

You're using the same acceptor instance for all your ports. That won't work. Moving the acceptor into the `Conn` object/tuple may help:

```
void listen(Port port) {
    auto& [acceptor, listening, sockets, processor] = ports[port];
    acceptor = {context, {{}, port}};

    while (ports[port].listening) {
        sockets.push_back(acceptor.accept());
        std::thread{
            processor, std::ref(sockets.back()), std::ref(*this)}
            .detach();
    }
}
```

However, you have to rethink your `close()` approach, as that is a data race again, but also, you're destructing the `socket` objects from another thread. If you need cancellation in Asio, you **need** asynchronous operations. There's no way you can safely destruct (or even `close()`) the socket while it is being used in a synchronous operation.

Here's the midway point that still has the data races and shutdown problems:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <thread>
#include <tuple>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using Server = struct PhysicalServer;
using Client = struct PhysicalClient;
using Socket = tcp::socket;

static boost::asio::system_executor context;

struct PhysicalServer {
    using Port      = uint16_t;
    using Processor = std::function<void(Socket& s, Server&)>;
    // using Conn      = std::tuple<bool, std::vector<Socket>,
    // Processor>;
    struct Conn {
        tcp::acceptor       acceptor{context};
        std::atomic_bool    listening = false;
        std::vector<Socket> sockets;
        Processor           processor;
    };

    std::map<Port, Conn> ports;

    void startListening()
    {
        for(auto& pair : ports)
            startListening(pair.first);
    }

    void stopListening()
    {
        for(auto& pair : ports)
            stopListening(pair.first);
    }

    void startListening(Port port)
    {
        ports[port].listening = true;
        std::thread{&PhysicalServer::listen, this, port}.detach();
    }

    void stopListening(Port port)
    {
        ports[port].listening = false;
    }

    void listen(Port port) {
        auto& [acceptor, listening, sockets, processor] = ports[port];
        acceptor = {context, {{}, port}};

        while (ports[port].listening) {
            sockets.push_back(acceptor.accept());
            std::thread{
                processor, std::ref(sockets.back()), std::ref(*this)}
                .detach();
        }
    }

    void setOnConnection(Port port, Processor const& proc) {
        ports[port].processor = proc;
    }

    void closeConnection() {
        for(auto& [key, tuple] : ports)
            closeConnection(key);
    }

    void closeConnection(Port port) {
        auto& sockets = ports[port].sockets;
        for(auto& socket : sockets)
            socket.close();
        sockets.clear();
    }

    void closeConnection(Socket& socket) {
        auto& sockets{ports[getSocketPort(socket)].sockets};

        auto it = std::find_if( //
            sockets.begin(), sockets.end(),
            [&](auto& s2) { return s2.local_endpoint() == socket.local_endpoint(); });

        if (it != sockets.end()) {
            socket.close();
            sockets.erase(it);
        }
    }

    size_t getClientCount() const
    {
        size_t total = 0;

        for (auto& [port, conn] : ports)
            total += getClientCount(port);

        return total;
    }

    size_t       getClientCount(Port port) const { return ports.at(port).sockets.size(); }
    Server::Port getSocketPort(Socket const& socket) { return socket.local_endpoint().port(); }

    void applyOnClient(std::function<void(Socket&)> const& action) {
        for (auto& [key, port] : ports) {
            applyOnClient(key, action);
        }
    }

    void applyOnClient(Port port, std::function<void(Socket&)> const& action) {
        auto& sockets = ports[port].sockets;
        std::for_each(sockets.begin(), sockets.end(), action);
    }
};

using Client = struct PhysicalClient;
struct PhysicalClient
{
    using Processor = std::function<void(Socket& s, Client&)>;
    Socket        socket{context};
    tcp::resolver resolver{context};
    Processor     processor;

    PhysicalClient()
        : socket(context)
        , resolver(context)
    {
    }

    void connect(std::string_view addr, std::string_view port)
    {
        if(socket.is_open())
        {
            return;
        }

        boost::asio::connect(socket, resolver.resolve(addr, port));
        std::thread{processor, std::ref(socket), std::ref(*this)}
            .detach();
    }

    void setOnConnection(Processor const& proc)
    {
        processor = proc;
    }
    void disconnect()
    {
        socket.close();
    }
    ~PhysicalClient()
    {
        disconnect();
    }
};

#include <iostream>

void clientCallback(Socket& socket, Client& /*client*/)
{
    std::cout << "Connected!\n";

    std::array<std::byte, 256> data;

    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            auto n =
                boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(data));
            std::cout << "Received " << n << " bytes" << std::endl;
        }
    } catch(boost::system::system_error& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to receive! " << e.what() << std::endl;
        // exit(1);
    }
}

void serverCallback(Socket& socket, Server& /*server*/)
{
    std::cout << "Client connected!\n";

    std::array<std::byte, 256> data;

    try
    {
        while(auto n = boost::asio::write(
                  socket, boost::asio::buffer(data)))
        {
            std::cout << "Sent " << n << " bytes" << std::endl;
        }
    } catch(boost::system::system_error& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to write! Client disconnected?\n";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char**) try {
    if (argc > 1) { // server
        PhysicalServer server;

        server.setOnConnection(10666, serverCallback);
        server.startListening(/*10666*/);

        std::cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
    } else { // client
        PhysicalClient client;

        client.setOnConnection(clientCallback);

        client.connect("127.0.0.1", "10666");
        std::cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
    }
} catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << "failure: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: While I check out your answer, I have two question: Do you have any resource to suggest to me about creating well-made and functioning servers/client programs with boost.asio? If you have the time and it's not a problem for you, could you elaborate a server class without those data races and shutdown issues?

Comment: I'd look on this site, really. The Asio examples are also a good start.

Comment: Also: so, if I got it correct, I need to have one acceptor per port?

Comment: By "this site" you mean StackOverflow or the Boost site?

Comment: stackoverflow.com, this site :)

Comment: I modified my code in a way that the acceptor is not static anymore. I tried connecting to the server from two different machines and the problem is still the same.

Comment: Did you try any of the other changes? If not, why not? If so, did the same problem still appear for you? (It didn't for me, as you can see).

Comment: As far I saw, the other change was the fact that you moved the objects I put in a tuple in a struct instead, right? Shouldn't the behaviour be the same though? Some other changes I found were relative to some syntactical elements. Sorry if I'm missing something, but it's a really stressing period. Maybe we can take the discussione elsewhere if it's better?

Comment: I would probably write a composable server using coroutines, like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53789865abed0459. If you want add shutdown (or other events to control listeners), I would consider the (experimental) channels like so: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac402fae943b95f7. If, like me you hate exception handling, you can achieve the same results using error-codes and `redirect_error`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/773906c1514a1573 (this was a late response to your first comment)

Comment: @darkonaito_ "should the behaviour be the same" - I'm only interested in "is the behaviour the same" (which _should_ be easily checkable). To be completely honest, I forgot most about this question/answer so it would take more time than I have currently to answer what else was changed. There's a good chance I mentioned things in my answer though :) (Oh yeah, I now remember, an essential change is that the code was made self-contained and complete, so it's easier to look at the behaviour)

Comment: Your example seems to work only some times, others not. I tried to rewrite my client and server classes as you did and I'm still getting the same multiple connection problem: when one new client connects the old one disconnects. I really don't know what to do. Is there a good ASIO resource that starts from the very basics and that is comprehensible by a beginner and uses modern ASIO? Studying using examples on stackoverflow is not a method that works that much with me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253826/discussion-between-darkonaito-and-sehe).